# What do I do in this case, is this Kufr?

Tags: shirk, punishment, tawba, kufr

I remember around three-two years, ago in a fit of rage, I insulted Allah, most merciful, most gracious. (I’m currently 15.) Now, I’ve been anxious to my mind,and have been having very bad thoughts because of my stupidness and have been in despair. How will Allah  forgive me for this. I have repeated my shahada, performed ghusl and prayed salat-al-tawba, and have been trying to stay consistent with the 5 prayers. How may Allah forgive this. Astagfirallah.

Answer (score 0):

Allah will surely forgive you..
For his forgiveness and mercy has no bounds.
This isnt kufr because at that time it might be that u havent hit puberty and unless a person has not hit puberty he is surely not accounted for his or her deeds
I hope Allah will guide you and remove these doubts from your heart brother

Answer (score 0):

If you repented sincerely, there is an extremely high chance Allah has already forgiven you. Allah forgives ALL SINS before the sun rises from the West.

Don’t worry, just repent sincerely and once you repented, completely forget about it, never doubt the mercy of Allah the almighty, the most merciful. Shaytan makes you always doubt the mercy of Allah to make you think that your sins will never be forgiven so that you just give up and leave Islam. That’s (one of) his plan.

What you did wasn’t kufr because kufr means disbelief, you didn’t disbelieve Islam, you just said it accidentally.

Allah is the most forgiving, the most merciful. Never doubt his unlimited forgiveness.

May Allah grant us all eternal Jannah.